# Changes not appearing in .apk file

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I am creating an Android application via PhoneGap for the first time.

I followed the PhoneGap quick start guide for Android on a Mac, and was able to setup the ADT bundle, and am using the standard Eclipse installation. I was able to get the Hello World app to appear on my Android devices (virtual and physical).

I then replaced the code in the assets/www directory with my custom HTML and JavaScript code that I want to test on the Android devices, but the old Hello World app still appears every time I run the app.

I have deleted the app.adk file from the file system and deleted the app from the Android device (using the Settings app).  The .apk file gets re-created, and the Console shows it is being copied to the Android device - however the old HTML "Hello World" app consistently appears.

I've run Project > Clean multiple times, and ran the ./clean and ./build scripts from the cordova directory in the Terminal.  I played around with the XML files in the res directory, and made some minor changes to the various .java files. There was some mention of the Hello World app in these files. Deleting them wasn't the solution.

I have also deleted the entire project and re-created it from scratch multiple times (using the phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/bin/create script, followed by running the File > New > Android Application Project wizard in Eclipse).

Is there something that I'm supposed to change or delete to force Eclipse to build my changes into the apk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had created a blank activity when running through the Android Application Project wizard.  The "Hello World" app I was looking at was the result of that blank activity.

I re-created the app and re-ran the Application Project wizard, but did not create an activity. This generated a "no launcher activity found" error. I then added a set of activity and intent-filter tags & their values to the AndroidManifest.xml file and saw my application.

The problem was not that the apk file was not updating - it was that I had not properly configured the activities.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this, when setting up my build environment on a second computer. Apparently **Phonegap only builds properly when your app is in `lib/<platform>/bin/<your_app_name>`.**

The fix for me was to re-run the `create` script using a plain 'ol directory name as the first argument. Something like `create myApp com.myDeveloperName.myApp myApp`.

Comment: @wolfet410 You should put your solution into an answer, so others can find it if they have the same problem.